# javascript runtime gallery buttons click event

Tags: javascript

There is a gallery which reads the data from a database.

Below of that there are some circles which shows the number of all data or records.

Each time a circle turns to yellow which indicates that what is the active post.

I have generate this mechanism by this way :

```
function drawCircles(activeIndex) {
    var off_html = '<img class="post_circle" src="../themes/dark/images/off.png"/>';
    var on_html = '<img class="post_circle" src="../themes/dark/images/on.png"  />';
    $('#circles').empty();

    for (var i = 1; i <= pcount; i++) {

        if (i != activeIndex) {
            $(off_html).appendTo($('#circles'));
        }
        else {
            $(on_html).appendTo($('#circles'));
        }

    }


}
```

**PCount = Count of All Posts...**

### #circles div is a bar which circles are in it.**

when we call

```
drawCircles(2)
```

The second circle turns to yellow.
Now I want to make a click event for that.I want to understand which circle has been clicked?
I have tried **.live** function , but I can't found that which circle has been clicked...

Comment: note : this function will be called every 5 seconds...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#circles img.post_circle').on('click', function(e) {
  // e.target is the circle clicked
});
```

Edit: Here is a fuller answer:

```
$(function(){
  var off_html = '<img class="post_circle" src="http://placehold.it/50x50/ff0000"/>';
  var on_html = '<img class="post_circle" src="http://placehold.it/50x50/ffff00"/>';

  var pcount = 5;

  $('#circles').empty();    
  drawCircles(3);

  function drawCircles(activeIndex) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= pcount; i++) {
      if (i != activeIndex) {
        $(off_html).data('index', i).appendTo($('#circles'));
      } else {
        $(on_html).data('index', i).appendTo($('#circles'));
      }
    }
  }

  $('#circles img.post_circle').on('click', function(e) {
    alert($(this).data('index'));
  });
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awilliams47/J5MW7/1/)

Comment: you know , i want the index of circle which was clicked.

Comment: You could add a `data-index` attribute to each circle and read that back in the click event handler.